# How can you filter list by property value in an int list?

Tags: c#, linq, list, contains

I've defined two lists and now want to filter the `escHistory` list by `Application` property matching the `filterRIDS` RID values.

But stepping through the LINQ that filters out the `escHistory` I get a return count of zero. Although the list does contain records with Application property values matching those defined in `filterRIDS`.

Question:

How can you filter list by property value in another list?

This is a basic gist of the filter code:

```
List<int> filterRIDS = new List<int> { 115841, 200463 };
List<Escalation> escHistory = new List<Escalation>();

//Filter list by RID's matching
escHistory = escHistory.Where(r => r.Application.Contains(filterRIDS.ToString())).ToList<Escalation>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You swapped the query

```
escHistory = escHistory.Where(r => filterRIDS.Contains(int.Parse(r.Application))).ToList();
```

Comment: Ok forgot to mention that `r.Application` is a string type like `123456 MyTestApp`. So in my case I would get get the substring before parsing to int. `escHistory = escHistory.Where(r => filterRIDS.Contains(int.Parse(r.Application.Substring(0, 6)))).ToList();
`

Comment: @BrianJ or you split `r.Application.Split(' ').First()`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `filterRIDS.ToString()` which returns name of `List<int>` class:

```
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]"
```

Of course you don't have history objects which contain this value in `Application` field. If you want to check whether `Application` string contains any string from given list:

```
escHistory = escHistory
     .Where(r => filterRIDS.Any(id => r.Application.Contains(id.ToString())))
     .ToList();
```